# http post does not upload files and get access vialotion on close my project Delphi

Tags: delphi, http-post, indy, access-violation, delphi-xe7

I have 2 problems !

**1:**

my application work like this :
add **file path** that I want to upload it to `listbox`, therefore upload all files that I added previously to listbox, one by one to my server!

the problem is that , the files does not upload , and I get these error message `Not Connected` and some times I get `Disconnected` messasge .

**2:**

When I close my application the access violation error raised to me !!!

I guess it's because `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`.

How can I solve these problems ????

This is my code !!

**Note:** I use `IdHttp` to upload files, and I didn't change in their properties , just drop it to my application and use it !

```
var
  StreamSendFiles: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  StreamSendFiles := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    StreamSendFiles.AddFile('upload_file', ListBox1.Items[0]);
    try
      IdHTTP1.Post('http://myserver.com/files', StreamSendFiles);
      ListBox1.Items.Delete(0);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage(' "Files" Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    StreamSendFiles.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown.  Your AV error has nothing to do with this code. As for the socket errors, my guess would be that the server is disconnecting on its end. Use a packet sniffer to verify. Maybe the server does not like your `POST` data. Are you sure the server is expecting a `multipart/form-data` POST to begin with? Why are you using `multipart/form-data` to send an individual file with no associated metadata fields? You may as well just use `TIdHTTP.Put()` instead, if the server allows PUT instead of POST.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ,Yes I'm sure, my server is expecting a `multipart/form-data` ,
and I used it because of its allow me to upload files and send POST data at the same time !
If I want to discard it , What I have to use instead of it ??? (`multipart/form-data`)

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. Please clarify.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , I need to ask you another question ,

How can I read the response from the server after uploading file done ???
Because I want to know the upload process is done or not !

Comment: `Post()` is a blocking function, it does not exit until the upload is finished. If the post fails, `Post()` raises an exception. Which the code above is already accounting for.